# PHP merge values of numeric arrays in corresponding keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

So consider an array with my 3 favorite fruits:

```
$array1 = array("Apple", "Banana","Raspberry")
```

I want to merge it with their own beautiful and natural color

```
$array2 = array("Green ", "Yellow ","Red ")
```

**So that the results would look like**

```
([0] => Green Apple [1] => Yellow Banane [2] => Red Raspberry)
```

I need something to be scalable (2 to 6 keys, always the same between arrays)

What I tried and results

- `array_combine($array2,$array1)`

  Result: `Array ( [Green ] => Apple
     [Yellow ] => Banana [Red ] => Raspberry )`
- `array_merge($array2,$array1)`
  Result: `Array ( [0] => Green [1] =>
     Yellow [2] => Red [3] => Apple [4] => Banana [5] => Raspberry )`
- `array_merge_recursive($array2,$array1)`
  Result: `Array ( [0] =>
     Green [1] => Yellow [2] => Red [3] => Apple [4] => Banana [5] =>
     Raspberry )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually should loop through arrays to combine them.

```
$combinedArray = array();
foreach ( $array1 as $key=>$value ) {
    $combinedArray[$key] = $array2[$key] . ' ' . $array1[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That should help me a lot with my fruits. I'm gonna accept your answer in few minutes since you're so fast.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the "space" with the concatenation. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply loop through each array.

```
$array1 = array("Apple", "Banana","Raspberry");
$array2 = array("Green ", "Yellow ","Red ")

$array3 = arrayCombine($array1, $array2);

function arrayCombine($array1, $array2) {
  $array_out = array();

  foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
    $array_out[] = $value . ' ' . $array2[$key];

  return $array_out;
}
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors `$array3 = function array_combine($array1, $array2);` should be `$array3 = array_combine($array1, $array2);`