# Merge Arrays But Join Corresponding Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to achieve the following functionality:

There is 5 textareas, the user inputs several words on different lines into the textarea, on click of a button it creates arrays from these textareas and the merges the array whilst appending the corresponding keys.

**Textarea 1:**

example 1

example 1 other

**Textarea 2:**

example 2

example 2 other

Using:

```
$col1 = $_POST['txta1']; $col1Array = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $col1));            
$col2 = $_POST['txta2']; $col2Array = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $col2));
```

This will now give me an array for each keyword, separating the textarea value based on a new line.

I now want to combine the 2 arrays so that key [0] appends the first array and so on, it should become

```
array([0]=>'example 1 example 2',[1]=>'example 1 other example 2 other');
```

In order for me to the echo out into another textarea, the results whilst should be:

example 1 example 2

example 1 other example 2 other

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179552/php-merge-values-of-numeric-arrays-in-corresponding-keys ?

Comment: As in the accepted answer to the question I linked: `$result = array_map(null, $col1Array, $col2Array);`

Comment: Oh, I guess that's not exactly the same since you're wanting to concatenate the resulting rows. sorry, I'll reopen it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass both the arrays to `array_map` to pivot them into the format you want, then implode the inner arrays so you end up with an array of strings rather than an array of arrays.

```
$result = array_map(
    function(...$row) { return implode(' ', $row); },
    $col1Array, $col2Array
);
```

Comment: Will try this now, just going to read into array_map so I learn what it does before aimlessly implementing.

Comment: @DanielVickers I made a small adjustment here. Just occurred to me that the inner array_map was not actually needed.